# How to make map in JavaScript change the object key

Tags: javascript

I have the following input data:

```
var persons = [
    {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
    {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
    {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"}
];
```

I need to change the value of the key in every object so expected output data is:

```
persons = [
    {fn : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
    {fn : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
    {fn : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"}
];
```

I am using map function in JavaScript but it is not working.

```
persons.map(x => x.firstname=x.fn);
```

Comment: do you want to change the existing objects or a new array with new objects?

Comment: Maybe `map` isn't the method you want

Comment: i need new array or whatever but output should like above key must be change in efficient way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thoughts was right but need to be a little bit changed:

```
persons = persons.map((x) => {
  return {
    fn : x.firstname,
    lastname : x.lastname
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) for objects. Then map the new property with the rest properties.

This proposal works only with newer JS or with [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/).

```js
var persons = [{ firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds" }, { firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye" }, { firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb" }];

console.log(persons.map(({ firstname: fn, ...rest }) => ({ fn, ...rest })));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use map like so by returning a new object.

```js
var persons = [
    {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
    {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
    {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"}
];

const newPersons = persons.map(person=>({fn:person.firstname, ln:person.lastname}));

console.log(newPersons);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let persons = [
    {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
    {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
    {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"}
];

let newPersons = persons.map(person => {
    return ({
       fn: person.firstname, lastname: person.lastname
    })
})
```

The `newPersons` array will be exactly the array that you need. Btw, I'm using `let` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach()`:

```js
var persons = [
    {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
    {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
    {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"}
];

persons.forEach((obj)=>{
  obj.fn = obj.firstname;
  delete obj.firstname;
});
console.log(persons);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use as follow:

```js
var persons = [
    {firstname : "Malcom", lastname: "Reynolds"},
    {firstname : "Kaylee", lastname: "Frye"},
    {firstname : "Jayne", lastname: "Cobb"}
];
var result = persons.map(current => { 
    var obj = {};
    obj.fn = current.firstname;
    obj.lastname = current.lastname;
    return obj;
  });
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [reduce](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjBgrGK2tPdAhWQ21MKHXQwDeEQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce&usg=AOvVaw1rZ36_gx-fT2lgEYKcfeI5)

```js
// Given
const persons = [
    {
        firstname: "Malcom",
        lastname: "Reynolds"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Kaylee",
        lastname: "Frye"
    },
    {
        firstname: "Jayne",
        lastname: "Cobb"
    }
];

// When
const people = persons.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
    previousValue.push({fn: currentValue.firstname, lastname: currentValue.lastname});

    return previousValue;
}, []);

// Then
console.log(people);
```